# How to extend or customize OOTB jsp files in CSC module of ATG?

Tags: atg, oracle-commerce

I am working on a CSC module of ATG. I am very new to this module and want to know how to overwrite jsp files which are already present in OOTB of CSC module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ATG Customer Service Center UI programming guide can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52191_02/Service.11-1/ATGServiceCenterUIProgGuide/html/index.html).  It has sections on best practices for customizing CSC.